# How to clear the bluetooth InputStream buffer

Tags: android, string, bluetooth, buffer

In the bluetoothChat example app, the sent and received data is added into a ArrayAdapter called `mConversationArrayAdapter`. There, each character is added into the array.

In my case, I have a String instead of an array because I don't need to send and receive several data, I only need to send one string, and receive one string each time.

The problem that I'm getting is that if I first receive a string like `hello world`, and then I receive a shorter one, the first is overwrited by the second, instead of deleting the first and writing the new.

So, if i first receive `hello world`, and then I supposse that I have to receive `bye`, what I really receive is `byelo world`.

So, how can I clear the buffer each time a receive what I want?

**Code Snipets**

Send data:

```
    byte[] send1 = message_full1.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send1);
```

Write call:

```
public void write(byte[] out) {
    /**Create temporary object*/
    ConnectedThread r;
    /**Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread*/
    synchronized (this) {
        if (GlobalVar.mState != GlobalVar.STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = GlobalVar.mConnectedThread;
    }
    /**Perform the write unsynchronized*/
    r.write(out);
}
```

Write Thread:

```
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        GlobalVar.mmOutStream.write(buffer);

        /**Share the sent message back to the UI Activity*/
        GlobalVar.mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalVar.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Finally, read Thread:

```
    public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[12];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    /**Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs*/
    while (true) {
        try {
            /**Read from the InputStream*/
            bytes = GlobalVar.mmInStream.read(buffer);

            /**Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity*/
            GlobalVar.mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalVar.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            GlobalVar.mTransmission.connectionLost();
            /**Start the service over to restart listening mode*/
            //GlobalVar.mTransmission.start();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post relevant code snippets...

Comment: @Sw4Tish, posted code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
buffer[bytes] = '\0';
```